# IIS 7.5 intermittently nonresponsive on bound public IP

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7, response, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm stumped. Searched high and low and can't find a clue.

I have this site that has private and public IPs bound. Been running fine until last Friday it would become unresponsive on the public IP - all the while fine when accessed via private IP on lan. It is intermittent and can last for minutes or hours.

Packet capture shows the request making it to the server.
Netstat shows windows making the tcp connection with client.
IIS tracing turned on to all requests (200-999) and no file generated nor an IIS log entry.
Changed to a different public IP and get the same behavior.
Nothing in the event logs.

I have never heard of this, anyone else have a clue? Appears the request is not being handed off to IIS.

Comment: Any possible chance another host on the net has the same IP? Last time I chased a ghost like this, even to thinking my NIC had gone bad, it turned out I'd allowed another host on the net to get a dup IP issued.

Comment: I should have mentioned that we verified no other host had that IP. And to reiterate, we see each unanswered request in wireshark and no corresponding trace in IIS.

Comment: Good enough. My next most evil suspect? Any chance of a firewall or security tool getting in the way on the public side? That might explain why you see the connect from the client, but never anything in IIS - something purposely intercepting and disallowing it.

Comment: No, that's not it either. The requests are always reaching the server. They can always be seen in packet capture. IIS is what is intermittent in responding, not requests intermittently making their way to the server.